# How to improve sensietivity of EventHandler to MouseDragged and MouseClicked events

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Using EventHandler, I notice that sometimes it thinks I was dragging the mouse, even though I was just clicking it.

Here is a simple example

```
 EventHandler[Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 1]],
 "MouseClicked" :> Print["mouse clicked"],
 "MouseDragged" :> Print["mouse being dragged"]
 ]
```

When I start clicking, even though I make sure the mouse is completely fixed and not moving, and I just keep clicking, and looking at the print messages, once in a while I see the dragging message come out.

I understand this can be sensitive to the mouse (but I have a good mouse), may be even the mouse pad, the OS, and any slight movement by hand, might cause this.

I wanted to ask if someone could try this and see if you notice this problem as well, and if someone knows some setting I can do in Mathematica to minimize this. I was looking for an option to EventHandler to set the time or delay as to when it decides the mouse being dragged, but see nothing.

Here is an example output of what I get on my system when I am just clicking after running the above code

```
mouse being dragged
mouse clicked   
mouse clicked    
mouse clicked    
mouse clicked    
mouse clicked    
mouse clicked    
mouse clicked
mouse clicked    
mouse being dragged    
mouse clicked   
mouse clicked
```

This is on windows 7, Mathematica 8.0.1

Thanks

Comment: I don't have any problems with this. I just get "mouse clicked". (Ubuntu 11.04, Mma 8.0.1 and 7.0.1)

Comment: Thanks for trying. But with the current program I have, on my system (windows 7), I can clearly see many times that the MouseDragged event is stealing the MouseClicked event. I can make few clicks, and they all go to the MouseDragged event instead. This makes MouseDragged useless to use as is. So I changed it to drag when the ControlKey is also pressed, and now there is no longer a conflict with the MouseClicked event. But I find that dragging a point on the screen while holding the ControlKey down is much slower than without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is not perfect, but seems to work better:

```
initMousePos = {-1, -1};
dragged = False;
EventHandler[
 Dynamic@Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 1]],
 "MouseDown" :>
  (initMousePos = MousePosition["Graphics"]),
 "MouseUp" :>
  If[EuclideanDistance[MousePosition["Graphics"], initMousePos] < 2 10^-1,
   Print["MouseClicked " <> ToString@MousePosition["Graphics"]],
   Sequence @@ {}],
 "MouseDragged" :> 
  If[EuclideanDistance[MousePosition["Graphics"], initMousePos] > 2 10^-1,
   Print["mouse being dragged " <> 
     ToString@MousePosition["Graphics"]], Sequence @@ {}]]
```

Comment: thanks, that is smarter way of doing it. This trick of checking the distance between mouse down and mouse up locations seems more reliable than checking for "MouseClicked" event! I will try your method in my demonstration I am working on now. I hope it will improve things.

Comment: btw, I am not sure why you added Sequenc@@{} there for the ELSE part of the above IF statement? I removed them, and it worked just as before. I assume there is a good reason for it, but I do not see it now.

Comment: @Nasser The problem is that `MouseDragged`is being fired too soon if the mouse is moving while clicking. I first tried to insert an hysteresis cycle, but it became too complicated. I am sure the code above can be improved a lot, but this is just a start. Regarding the `Sequence[ ]` thing, I put it there in case you want to call the whole thing as a function with a mandatory returning value. Remove it if you feel that part useless.